# iPhone BLE / GATT interface

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I am developing a BLE library for Node JS. I discovered my own iPhone and I found the following GATT services and characteristics:

```
service d0611e78bbb44591a5f8487910ae4366
characteristic { uuid: '8667556c9a374c9184ed54ee27d90049',
  props: [ 'write', 'notify', 'extendedProperties' ] }

service 9fa480e0496745429390d343dc5d04ae
characteristic { uuid: 'af0badb15b9943cd917aa77bc549e3cc',
  props: [ 'write', 'notify', 'extendedProperties' ] }

service 180f
characteristic { uuid: '2a19', props: [ 'read', 'notify' ] }

service 1805
characteristic { uuid: '2a2b', props: [ 'read', 'notify' ] }
characteristic { uuid: '2a0f', props: [ 'read' ] }

service 180a
characteristic { uuid: '2a29', props: [ 'read' ] }
characteristic { uuid: '2a24', props: [ 'read' ] }
```

Now I am wondering what they do. Is there any documentation / specification for this? I could not find much by googling.

Comment: All 16-bit uuids can be found in the Bluetooth specification and on the Bluetooth web site. The longer 128-bit uuids are custom uuids anyone can define and use so you must in that case see if the vendor has some documentation for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the 16-bit standard/registered services, you want the [GATT Services](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services/) list.

180f is Battery Service.

1805 is Current Time Service.

180a is Device Information.

The long-form (128-bit) services are custom, unregistered services.

d0611e78bbb44591a5f8487910ae4366 is the Apple Continuity service.

I don't know what 9fa480e0496745429390d343dc5d04ae is.